# Adding The Anchor Text As The Title Dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, title

Currently I have this html code with me

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Google Website</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo Website</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing Website</a><br />
```

Now I want that text of respected anchor tag should become the title of that respected anchor tag

Answer (score 2):

you can use each loop for anchor tag and get the text of current tag and add it to following anchor tag as its title

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
            });
        });       
    </script>
```

Comment: Worked Like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add title attribute

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google Website">Google Website</a><br />
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" title="Yahoo Website">Yahoo Website</a><br />
<a href="http://www.bing.com" title="Bing Website">Bing Website</a><br />
```

Or Using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr("title", title);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that he is looking for a JavaScript solution to automate this.

Comment: i want it dynamically I know how to add title .

Answer (score 1):

Since `.attr()` accepts a callback function, you could use:

```
$('a').attr("title", function(){
    return $(this).text();
});
```

```js
$('a').attr("title", function () {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Website</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo Website</a><br />
    <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing Website</a><br />
```